# Delta Dirac integrals

Tags: dirac-delta

Evaluate the following integrals:

$$
\int_0^\infty e^x \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right) \delta \left(x^2-1\right) dx\\
\int_0^\infty e^x \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right) \delta'\left(x^2-1\right) dx
$$

Would the first one be 0 since x can't be both 1 and -1 at the same time? And I'm not sure how to handle the second integral at all.

Comment: Is this question (v2) on hold for being unclear, for technical reasons, for being blatant homework, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the identity $$\delta(f(x))=\sum_c\frac{\delta(x-c)}{\lvert f'(c)\rvert},$$ where the sum is over all real numbers $c$ such that $f(c)=0$.

For the second integral, use integration by parts to get rid of the derivative on the delta function.